# How do you make string from textbox.text give an integer value, when using an array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm using an integer array to hold a value, so the function can check the value in that Textbox. In this case answers(4). When this equals 1, a label is outputted (after going through the function) saying if the text entered into the textbox is true or false.

However, when the text is typed in the textbox and the button is pressed, I get an error because the array is integer and the text inside the textbox wont do because it is a string.

How do I make it so the text input gives out an integer value?

```
Public Class Form1

    Public score As Integer
    Dim answers(10) As Integer

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxTq4.TextChanged    
        If TxTq4.Text = "true" Then
            Me.score = Me.score + 1
            answers(4) = 1
        ElseIf TxTq4.Text = "True" Then
            Me.score = Me.score + 1
            answers(4) = 1
        ElseIf TxTq4.Text = ("") Then
            Me.score = Me.score + 0
        End If    
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If answers(4) = answer(TxTq4.Text) Then
            lq4.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function answer(ByVal val As Integer)
        Dim numberTrue As Boolean    
        If answers(4) = 1 Then
            lq4.Text = "True"
            lq4.BackColor = Color.Green
            numberTrue = True    
        Else
            lq4.Text = "False"
            numberTrue = False
            lq4.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If    
        Return numberTrue    
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Could you do similar logic as in your `TextBox1_TextChanged` event? If `TxTq4.Text = "true"` assign a variable the value of 1. Then if `answers(4) = variable`, proceed into the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code **but** the text must be *true* or *false* (upper or lower-case doesn't matter) otherwise you have a problem:

```
If answers(4) = answer( Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToBoolean(TxTq4.Text)) ) Then
```